# Wordpress | Classic Editor to Gutenberg Editor for a page in the subsite

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a WordPress multisite and classic editor is network activated. I have a request from a page owner on one of the subsites to switch to Gutenberg editor for their page alone. Is it possible to switch the editor for a page alone on a subsite?